# .NET Remote debugging domain/networking issues

Tags: .net, networking, dns, remote-debugging

I have been trying to implement remote debugging in two different scenarios both without success.

1: Debug a server that is in our office but not on our network, we use BT and the server is on a static peer IP address while the rest of the LAN is on a single dynamic IP. 
Ever since this was setup with the peer IP the server dissappeared from our workgroup ((I think I may have to contact BT regarding this). More info here regarding peer ip's for those interested: http://business.forums.bt.com/t5/Broadband-and-internet/Static-IP-s-on-BT2700HGV-aren-t-always-static/m-p/17183)

But the server allows users on the LAN to RDP where users from a WAN cannot.

2: Our production server is outsourced. Is it possible to remote debug over WAN?

Both fail when I try to attach to process.

The error message returned when trying to attach to a process on the office server using username@ip-address is:

Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio remote debugging monitor named 'username@ip-address' The visual studio remote debugger on the target computer cannot connect back to this computer. Authentication failed. Please see help for assistance

That is with the firewall turned off on the client (my own) development machine. On the server machine the debugging monitor logs the connection.

The server on the WAN returns this error:

unable to connect to the microsoft visual studio remote debugging monitor named 'username@web-domain' The Debugger cannot connect to the remote computer. This may be because the remote computer does not exist or a firewall may be preventing communication to the remote computer. Please see help for assisstance.

The server does have a firewall but our office IP has full access RDP, FTP etc..

I feel totally stuck now and I am making no headway at all, any help greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible to debug over WAN. If your server is behind physical firewalls you will need to allow access, not just windows firewall. If the two machines are behind the same firewall then be sure to run 'msvsmon.exe' for your specific environment.

Make sure you are not using any Express versions of visual studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Your best bet is to get a VPN tunnel to your host and possibly to the other network in your office (I need more info about the network to make a better suggestion).

Comment: Yea the firewall should be open to my IP however I'm not sure I need to get onto our server host boffins and pester them once more about setting up a VPN. I gave up last time but things have changed since then. Will hopefully have more details next week.

Comment: Great. My overall recommendation is to setup a VPN tunnel, it's a safer way to go and when you're done, be sure to disable remote debugging on your server.